# Batch inserts with resque

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, background-process, resque

I am currently trying to set up a task that collects a bunch of objects, and then queues a background task to batch insert them to a database.. and then repeats.

I have been working a little bit with resque, to see if i could get that set up.. But i am having a hard time figuring out how to pass an array of objects to a background job.

Can anyone help me out?

---

edit: 
I should probably mention i am using `gem "ar-extensions"` to do batch imports

Comment: You'll really want to just pass an array of IDs, not the objects themselves, right?

Comment: no, i dont think so... because the db rows have not been created yet. thats the whole point. When i do `MyObject.new(...)` it doesnt have an id, until i actually do `MyObject.import([MyObject.new(..), MyObject.new(..)])` and thats the bit i'm trying to put in the background

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass object(s) since both are different processes. I would suggest to move the collection of objects code as well to background job.